# robot framework: test case cannot load keyword in resource file that import in the test suite's parent test suite folder

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

[image]

Hi, I am using robot framework to automate testing of a website, and the image above is the structure of test in the RIDE:

- Test: a test suite folder, and I import resource file here, which is in the "**init**.robot" under the folder
- Sub1: a sub test suite, import nothing
- test: a test case

My problem is: in the test case "test", robot cannot recognize the keyword that imported in the "Test" test suite folder, because there will be more sub test suites, like sub2, sub3, how can I import resource in one place? I don't want to import the resource file in every test suite, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain an imports. Below is an example of such a chain and reuse. In this example we have a single `resources.robot` that imports all of the different `sub*.robot` files. This is the only file that imports these.

Then there are two `testcases*.robot` files that proceed to import `resources.robot` and are able to access the content of the `sub*.robot` keywords.

**resources.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    ../resources/sub1.robot
Resource    ../resources/sub2.robot
Resource    ../resources/sub1.robot
```

**testcases1.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    ../resources/resources.robot

*** Test Cases ***
TC
   No Operation
```

**testcases2.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    ../resources/resources.robot

*** Test Cases ***
TC
   No Operation
```

As discussed in the comments, that any keyword imported in the `__init__.robot` file is not available beyond that file. This is clearly described in the Robot Framework User Guide section on [Initialization files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#initialization-files).

That said, if the effort of including the master resource file in each suite file undesirable, then an alternative approach is to load the resource file using a listener at the start of each Suite. The documentation on Listeners can be found here: [Docs](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface)

A new example:

**AddResourceListener.py**

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class AddResourceListener(object):
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start_suite(self, name, attributes):
        BuiltIn().import_resource('${EXECDIR}/resource.robot')
```

**resource.robot**

```
*** Keywords ***
Resource Keyword
    Log    "Keyword Executed from Resource File"
```

**TestCase.robot**

```
*** Test Cases ***
TC
    Resource Keyword
```

Then run your regular robot command with the additional argument `--listener AddResourceListener.py` and you'll be able to use the keyword regardless if it's imported or not.

Comment: as per user, he don't want to import the resource file in every suite, i am not sure if there is any other way to do it.

Comment: @pankajmishra yes, that is the point, top level is a test suite directory, and under this top test suite directory are some of the test suites, I want to import my resource file at the top test suite directory, so that I will not need to import my resource file at all the sub test suites one by one

Comment: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#initialization-files

Comment: @yyzhang14922. Initialization files are not a solution as the documentation clearly states that any keywords loaded there will not be available in the actual test cases.

Comment: @pankajmishra Sorry, missed that.

Comment: @A.Kootstra Yes, the documentation not said that whether the lower test suites can inherit the resource file imported at the parent test suite directory, see this: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2859

Comment: @A.Kootstra Your answer is the only one solution now, so I accept it, thank you!

Comment: The referred GitHub issue has been closed with the same answer as given above. any keyword imported in any `__init__.robot` is not available beyond that `__init__.robot` file.

Comment: @A.Kootstra: Thanks for your solution, which is working fine on actual test runs, however, keep in mind that dryruns will then fail with "keyword not found" errors, since the Listener is not executed.

Comment: @A.Kootstra If I make the library as a listener by define the `ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER ` then not pass `AddResourceListener.py` by `--listener`, the test failed with `No keyword with name 'some keyword' found.`. So, it is must be passed by the `--listener ` option?

Comment: Not sure what the problem/question is @yyzhan14922. Including the file via de CLI is necessary, as it is a listener.